# Why doesn't git-annex map realize Einstein is one repository?

Tags: git-annex

### TLDR

Have I confused [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) into thinking one machine is actually two?

### Background

I have a [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) repository that has copies on three machines: Watt, Einstein, and Heisenberg in addition to a [special remote](http://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/) on S3.

Einstein is a server, and has both external public IPs and internal private (RFC1918) ones. Watt is on the LAN, and uses Einstein's LAN IP. Heisenberg is a laptop, so uses one of its public IPs (so it can still sync even when remote).

When I run `git-annex map` on Watt, this is what I get:

[image: output of <code>git-annex map</code> showing two Einsteins]

(Note that HeisenbergW5 is one of Heisenberg's host names, it has multiple interfaces...)

### The Question

That looks awfully like [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) doesn't realize the Einstein that Heisenberg is sync'ing with is the same as the one Watt is sync'ing with (but, oddly, only in one direction). Do I need to worry about this, or is it just a minor issue with `git-annex map`?

Comment: Shot in the dark: resolving IP for one and host for the other path.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the name & path shouldn't matter at all here, each repository has a UUID and also a description that gets passed around in the meta data branch.